# Actionbar menu item background on select

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I am using sherlock actionbar and made custom action bar using differnt color (blue) . When there are menu items . as i click on menu item . items background turns in to gray . Not able to point which attribute of the style is making this effect had checked the most possibility . any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after some analysis found following answer

```
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
```

The issue is you need to override these attributes in your application. donot try changing in actionbar apk libary. that was the point i missed while fixing this.

Comment: works! It's completely fine to accept your own answer. Please, do it, so the question doesn't show up in the 'unanswered' list.